# how to differentiate multiple button action in the controller for phalcon framework? example; submit and update and clear button

Tags: php, button, phalcon

```html
<?php echo $this->tag->form("index/index"); ?>
    <label for="nameInput">name</label>
    <?php echo $this->tag->textField("nameInput"); ?>
    <label for="typeInput">type</label>
    <?php echo $this->tag->textField("typeInput"); ?>
    
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="update">
</form>
```

And in the controller.. something like this..

```html
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    //example
    echo 'update';
}
elseif (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //example
    echo 'submit';
}
```

I'm still trying to learn Phalcon step by step. theres not many documentation on this particular problem for me. i think its something to do with me not understanding Phalcon completely. if someone could help guide me, it would be a lot appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to give your submit buttons names.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<input type="submit" name="update" value="update">
```

When a form is submit with a submit button, its name:value pair is sent with the form. You'd need to give it a name in order to find it in in the $_POST array.  Also please avoid the name "submit" for submit buttons because it can make it can create issues for JavaScript's submit() method.  Rather than checking both $_POST['update'] and $_POST['submit'], you should instead use the same name for both of your submit buttons and distinguish them on the backend with their value like so:

```
<input type="submit" name="act" value="submit">
<input type="submit" name="act" value="update">
```

Then you'd check

```
if (isset($_POST['act']) && $_POST['act'] === 'update') {
    echo 'update';
}
elseif (isset($_POST['act']) && $_POST['act'] === 'submit') {
    echo 'submit';
}
```

Assuming you're not using [scream](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.scream.php), this can actually be shortened with the [silence operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) like so:

```
if (@$_POST['act'] === 'update') {
    echo 'update';
}
elseif (@$_POST['act'] === 'submit') {
    echo 'submit';
}
```

If you need your submit button to display one value and submit another, you can use the button element like so:

```
<button type="submit" name="act" value="submit">New Entry</button>
<button type="submit" name="act" value="update">Edit Entry</button>
```

You can also use hidden elements to do just that, and use multiple forms.

As you're new to Phalcon, I'd suggest playing around with some simpler examples like [invoice](https://github.com/phalcon/invo) and [vökuró](https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro) which appear on the "tutorials" section of the following page:
https://docs.phalconphp.com/3.4/en

Comment: My god it works! thanks a lot. i've explored a whole bunch with my limited knowledge without progress for a long time. Thank you sir. and here i thought i can never did what i did normally while using phalcon framework or any framework(phalcon is my first framework im learning hahaha). ive already voted this answer. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutons, and my refactoring of your code will be:

1. Do not use multiple `Submit` buttons on same form. Use simple forms and `IF-logic` while rendering form
2. complete API and UI separation (form buttons has JS handlers and Phalcon is just API backend)
3. your example but route/dispatch to different actions (`if _POST['submit'] && _POST['somethingelse']`), more generic

Comment: 1) can you please elaborate further on why? and the further on the IF-logic. what do you mean? in my understanding its simple and straight forward to just assign a process to each specific button. but i might be wrong. please guide me.
2) I dont understand sorry.
3) im dont think my solutions will work in phalcon framework hence why i ask the question. im also having trouble understanding the whole route/dispatch thing. thank you for your reply :)

Comment: About first point - Phalcon default behaviour is MVC, it means - view has form and button, button has action, action has logic on model update. By adding additional button the update logic became complex and it also depends on POST-ed data. Mixing different behaviours on one view/form to one action and many-IFs is no-way. 

This is why developers use Rest API  (see 2. option)

Comment: i see. im still crawling through MVC. i'll take note of what you say while learning. thanks for your guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

Phalcon provides a [Phalcon\Http\Request](https://docs.phalconphp.com/3.3/en/api/phalcon_http_request) object accessible from the controller.
It is strongly recommended to use it.

Here is a simple example with a POST request :

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function processFormAction()
    {
        // Retrieve value of <input name="foo" />
        $form_field = $this->request->getPost('foo');

        if ($form_field === "bar") {
            echo "Foo = bar";
        } else {
            echo "Foo != bar";
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

In your case if you want two submit buttons in your form with different function then you have many solutions:

**First solution**

Use JavaScript to submit your form and defines two routes, one for save and other for update.

```
<input type="submit" name="saveBtn" value="Click me">
<input type="submit" name="updateBtn" value="Click me">
```

Bind click on each buttons and set the route url according to the desired action.

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="saveBtn"]').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        form.attr('action', 'url-to-save');
        form.submit();
    });

    $('input[name="updateBtn"]').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        form.attr('action', 'url-to-update');
        form.submit();
    });
});
```

In your controller, you have two methods

```
public function saveAction() {
    // Do save
}

public function updateAction() {
    // Do update
}
```

**Second solution**

Give each one a name, the clicked one will be sent through as any other input

```
<input type="submit" name="saveBtn" value="Click me">
<input type="submit" name="updateBtn" value="Click me">
```

In your controller :

```
$submitSave = $this->request->getPost('saveBtn', 'string', false);
$submitUpdate = $this->request->getPost('updateBtn', 'string', false);

if ($submitSave) {
    echo "This is a save";
} elseif ($submitUpdate) {
    echo "This is an update";
}
```

**Third solution**

Define name as array

```
<input type="submit" name="submit[save]" value="Click me">
<input type="submit" name="submit[update]" value="Click me">
```

In your controller :

```
$submit = $this->request->getPost('submit');

if (!empty($submit)) {
    if (!empty($submit['save'])) {
        echo "This is a save";
    } elseif (!empty($submit['update'])) {
        echo "This is an update";
    }
}
```

Comment: i think i understand these part. just i dont know how to differentiate process for multiple button in one form.